# Is there a way to detect which millennium a NSDate is in?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have an `NSDate` from a string of `01/01/14`. Unfortunately the strings are saved with two digits so I have no idea if the year is from 1900's or 2000's. But I want create some intelligent code to guess what millennium and century the full year is. I know for a fact (based on the application I'm creating) that the year can't be below 1900 in 99% of cases.

I have converted the date to now show four digits on but it's now being displayed as `01/01/0014`.

Is there a way to detect the millennium of the `NSDate` as `0` and make my changes accordingly?

What I really want to do is something like this (pseudo code):

```
if (millennium == 0 && decade < 15 && decade > 99)
{
   millennium = 2;
   century = 0;
   // change the date to 2000's here
}
else if (millennium == 00)
{
   millennium = 1;
   century = 9;
   // change the date to 1900's here
}
```

Comment: You could check if the date is before the year 100, and if so, set the year to be `existingDateYear + 1900` (also pseudo code)

Comment: This is awful. The first millennium start at 1AD and ended in December 1000AD. The second millennium ended in December 2000AD, and the third millennium started with Jan 1st, 2001.

Comment: @Stonz2, the numbers with 2 digits are always between 0 and 99 and it never goes over 99 in decimal system... therefore, all dates between year 0 and year 99, so checking whether the year is less than 100 is not really effective here, because it would be always true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters your pseudocode isn't quite right (the first if statement is an impossible condition as decade can't be less than 15 and more than 99 at the same time).

I have created a basic solution using `NSDateComponents` and made up my own conditions for when to change the year which you can easily change.

```
NSDate *date; // this is your date

NSDateComponents* components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDateCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

if([components year] < 15) // 2000 to 2015
{
  [components setYear:[components year] + 2000];
}
else if([components year] < 100) // 1915 to 1999
{
  [components setYear:[components year] + 1900];
}

date = [NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an oldschool stuff (from the 80s) here to convert a year in 2 digits to year in 4 digits.

```
int finalYear = (19 + (yearIn2Digits < 50)) * 100 + yearIn2Digits;
```

then you can use that `finalYear` value to build up the proper `NSDate` object.

the covered interval is always 100 years and it is up you where you'd like to draw the line. the original idea worked between 1950 and 2049 – as you see in the formula, – but you can refine it for covering better your actual bounds of years.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend hardcoding this logic. 
what if you want to convert a date which is 1908 , or 2015.

A smarter way to do this is as follows :

```
-(BOOL)isInCurrentDecade:(NSDate*)date{

  // I don't recollect the api to extract year from NSDate
  NSInteger tmpYear = [date year];
  NSInteger currentYear = [[NSDate date] year];

  return  tmpYear > currentYear%100

}
```

What I am doing here is that I compare 87 , 04 , 99 with current year digit's 14. and if it's between 00 and now then its current decade. This code is more robust than your's because it's relative comparison with current date

o/p of the code is as follow as of year 2014 :

```
87 - > NO  // in 90's
99 -> NO
04 - > YES // in 2000's  
12 - > YES
```

Edge case occurs when your date includes 1/1/14 if you want it to be filtered in current decade replace the '>' with  ' >=" .

Comment: yes, but the `15` can be in `2015` (e.g. for a deadline) and your agorithm would say that is in `1915`, therefore the imaginary deadline overdued by cca. 100 years.

Comment: @holex if you need that then use '>=' operator. I mentioned that in my edit.

Comment: okay, and what about `2016`, `2017` etc...? can `16` or `17` be a valid date after `2000`, or they must be only `1916` or `1917`...?

Comment: @holex if you 16 right now (as of 2014) it means it refers to to 1916 because the records does not mention about future dates. But if you do it in 2020 then the probability that it is 2016 is high and that is what this algorithm is gonna do.

Comment: yes, I know, that is exactly what I did like to highlight here. the developer has to draw the line and hardcode it, because the application will start to work differently year after year, on the same input database and it messes up the dates.

Comment: @holex if your record does not have future dates then this will be more robust. If does not have any point of failure. With hardcoding you do have edge cases on intervals.

Comment: my issue is shown by the following example here: let us get `15` as date of birth; that would be converted to `1915` in `2014`, but in `2016` the same date of birth becomes suddenly `2016` which would be just not correct, and raises a bug in the same applcation on the same database. you may understand what I'd like to tell you.

Comment: @holex I understand that bug. If you enter 15 right now its a future date and hence this algorithm will fail. It will only work if you enter dates which are from 1900 to current year and will work without failing for a single case.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSDateFormatter and its property "twoDigitStartDate". You set this to the *earliest* date that you want to be able to enter with a two digit year. No complicated logic needed, and easy to update. Now data entry is one thing, but storing a date "with a two digit year", that's criminal.

And it handles things like "I want to be able to store anything starting with the start of the tax year 1985 in two digits, that is April 1st 1985". Then April 1st 85 will be in 1985, while March 31st 85 will be in 2085. With no effort.